# passing props as graphql mutation argument in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, graphql, graphql-js

My Code looks like this:

```js
interface MutationProps{
  username: any,
  Mutation: any
}
const UseCustomMutation: React.FC<MutationProps> = (MutationProps: MutationProps) => {
  
  
  
  const [myFunc, {data, error}] = useMutation(MutationProps.Mutation);

  useEffect(() => {
    myFunc({variables:{username: MutationProps.username}}) 
    console.log(JSON.stringify(data))
    console.log(JSON.stringify(error, null , 2))
  }, [])
 return data 
}


export const DisplayUser = () => {
  const GET_USER = gql`
  
 mutation GetUser($username: String!){
getUser(username: $username) {
pfp
username
password
age
CurrentLive
ismod
description
fullname
}
}

 `
 const {username} : {username: any} = useParams()
 const MyData = UseCustomMutation(username, GET_USER)
 console.log(JSON.stringify(MyData))
```

But I get this error back: ×

> Argument of undefined passed to parser was not a valid GraphQL DocumentNode. You may need to use >'graphql-tag' or another method to convert your operation into a document

Comment: It seems you're using typescript. Aren't you getting a clear type error from `UseCustomMutation(username, GET_USER)`?!

Comment: Also, don't use `any` in your `MutationProps` interface. Be precise!

Comment: thank u @Bergi, i changed type of GET_USER to Document node and now its working

Answer (score 0):

How about your code looks like this:

```
interface MutationProps {
  username: string;
  Mutation: any;
}
const UseCustomMutation: React.FC<MutationProps> = ({ username, Mutation }) => {
  const [functionForDoingAction, { data, loading, error }] = useMutation(
    Mutation,
    {
      variables: {
        username,
      },
    }
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    // fn trigger for change data
    functionForDoingAction({
      variables: {
        username: "string_value",
      },
    });
    console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
    console.log(JSON.stringify(error, null, 2));
  }, []);

  if (loading) return "loading...";

  if (error) return `Submission error! ${error.message}`;

  return data;
};

export const DisplayUser = () => {
  const GET_USER = gql`
    mutation GetUser($username: String!) {
      getUser(username: $username) {
        pfp
        username
        password
        age
        CurrentLive
        ismod
        description
        fullname
      }
    }
  `;
  const { username }: { username: string } = useParams();
  const MyData = UseCustomMutation(username, GET_USER);
  console.log(JSON.stringify(MyData));
};
```

you can pass an argument directly to the useMutation hook which they provide as an Options parameter. Or is the direct trigger function from the hook you get.

Comment: Did you install `graphql-tag` package then added on the top `import gql from 'graphql-tag'`? It' parses GraphQL query strings into the standard GraphQL AST.

Comment: i imported it from @apollo/client , is there any diffrence beetwen those two?

Comment: not so much but it recommends in the err. one is caches the parse result of the query so every time gql call from the cache. docs: https://www.npmjs.com/package/graphql-tag